# css progress indicator with arrows

Tags: html, css, progress

i need help, i am trying to replicate this kind of progress indicator, but i can't figure it out.

What i want:

[image]

What i have: http://jsfiddle.net/AQWdM/

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-size: 13px;
}

ul.progress li.active {
  background-color: #dc9305;
}

ul.progress li {
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
}

ul.progress {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.progress li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  min-width: 130px;
  position: relative;
}

ul.progress li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  right: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #7e7e7e;
}

ul.progress li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  right: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
}

ul.progress li.beforeactive:before {
  background-color: #dc9305;
}

ul.progress li.active:before {
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
}

ul.progress li.active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #dc9305;
}

ul.progress li:last-child:after,
ul.progress li:last-child:before {
  border: 0;
}

ul.progress li a {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 6px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="progress">
  <li><a href="">Qualify</a></li>
  <li class="beforeactive"><a href="">Develop</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="">Propose</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Close</a></li>
</ul>
```

First, my example has "beforeactive" class - i would like to avoid this, so i can just mark item as active. Also, arrows on my example are not best set up - on image where is what i want, it has better set up arrows (the are more thick at starting).

I need your help to:

1.) Create better css, clearly i am not good at css, so not to require beforeactive class, also to properly color backgrounds, and to be optimized - there can be hundrets of this lists per page

2.) Create arrow to match the one on the design i want to have

3.) It needs to be dynamic, since sometimes it will be small, somtimes it will be large, it needs to be able to cope with different font sizes (maybe use em or percentage - i used px just to test stuff)

4.) IF - AND ONLY IF IS POSSIBLE SIMPLE WAY - to make it for example whole long 600px; and current active one is longest, others have fixed size, and the active one always fills up the rest of it. So if first is active, it takes 400px, and rest fill in 200px, when we activate second, to animate making others size down, and second one size up. I use jquery, so it's ok to use his anymations, but i prefer css animations (there will be thousands of lines of javascript code - so i try to use javascript as little as possible for ui)

Thank you

Comment: Did you Do that Css part by yourself i mean the one in jsfiddle example

Comment: Yes, i wrote it. Why?

Comment: If yes you are not at bad at Css

Comment: I'm sure not good - otherwise i would not need help :) (i'm programmer, asp.net, sql, etc... not designer)

Comment: Well thats kind of basic CSS. @user3127499

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use one pseudo rotated element and draw it on the far left side. *the first will be out of sight, so no need to worry about last `li`, set `overflow` on `ul` to hide `overflow`ing parts :).*

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/FnKim/)** and  CSS

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  font-size: 13px;
}

ul.progress li.active {
  background-color: #dc9305;
}

ul.progress li {
  background-color: #7e7e7e;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: 0.5em;
}

ul.progress li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 0.4em;
  width: 1.2em;
  padding-top: 1.2em;
  ;
  border: solid white;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  box-shadow: 5px -5px 0 3px #7e7e7e
}

ul.progress li.active:after {
  box-shadow: 6px -6px 0 3px #dc9305;
}

ul.progress {
  list-style: none;
  margin:2px 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width:max-content;
}

ul.progress li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  min-width: 130px;
  position: relative;
  transition: min-width 0.5s;
}

ul.progress li a {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 6px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.progress li:hover {
  min-width: 300px;
}

ul.progress li:before {
  content: '\2714'
}

ul.progress li.active:before,
ul.progress li.active~li:before {
  content: ''
}
```

```html
<ul class="progress">
  <li class="active"><a href="">Qualify</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Develop</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Propose</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Close</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="progress">
  <li><a href="">Qualify</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="">Develop</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Propose</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Close</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="progress">
  <li><a href="">Qualify</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Develop</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="">Propose</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Close</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="progress">
  <li><a href="">Qualify</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Develop</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Propose</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="">Close</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

Do not forget to add vendor-prefix or use a script to care of it.

---

over `li` to see them grow with `transition`, check marks added too via CSS to `li` ahead `.active` class

Comment: wow, thanks, this is great, works just the way i wanted 
it took me 2 hours to wrote my example and took you only couple of minutes to do it proper way :)

Comment: @CodeMonkey just added the checkmark and turn on prefix free on demo, but, you know i'm a really bad develloper ;)

Comment: but very good at css :) Thank you once again, this is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/8D2Ss/1/)

Please check this and see is this what you were looking for

```
<ul class="progress">
    <li><a href="">✔ Qualify</a></li>
    <li class="beforeactive"><a href=""> ✔ Develop</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Propose</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Close</a></li>
</ul>
```

Css

```
body {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-size: 13px;
}

ul.progress li.active {
    background-color: #dc9305;
}

ul.progress li {
    background-color: #7e7e7e;
}

ul.progress {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.progress li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    min-width: 130px;
    position: relative;

}

ul.progress li:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #7e7e7e;
}

ul.progress li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
}

ul.progress li.beforeactive:before {
    background-color: #dc9305;
}

ul.progress li.active:before {
    background-color: #7e7e7e;
}
ul.progress li.active:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #dc9305;
}

ul.progress li:last-child:after,
ul.progress li:last-child:before {
    border: 0;
}

ul.progress li a {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 6px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.progress li:hover {

  min-width:300px;

}
```

### Output

[image: O/p]

Comment: thank you, i already accepted answer from GCyrillus - since his does also animate - but you did exactly as i requested (except animation part) - so i will mark yours also as proper answer - it looks like anyone can do this - except me :)

Comment: Hey i just got lucky thats all hey you can only accept one as answer but can upvote multiple answers

Comment: i will upvote it once i will have enough reputition (i'm new here), thank you